# Cast button missing in Codelabs course

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to learn how to make a Cast feature, so I started this codelabs tutorial
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/index.html#1

The tutorial gave me 2 projects: app-start (the program I have to modify) and app-done (the complete program)
I followed instructions until step 5 where i should add the cast button.
It doesn't work, nor in modified app-start nor in app-done.

Other apps with cast feature (like youtube) show my Tv without a problem, but this doesn't.

My doubt is about Cast Developer ID that I'll need in future apps, but it says that for this one will be used a sample one.

Did someone found another problem or I just have to buy my Cast Developer ID?

Comment: Have you found any solution ? are you using chromecast or you have non android smart TV?

Comment: @Davide have you find the solution ? . I also stuck on same isuue.

Comment: @RavindMaurya if I remember well the Cast Developer ID was an old version and I found a new one in documents attached or the problem was that my television was not Android but webOs (LG) or Tizen (Samsung)

Answer (score 2):

Did you register the chromecast device you have under **Cast Receiver Devices** in **Google Cast SDK Console**? If not you'll have to do this, wait for 15 minutes then restart your chromecast.  I don't think you can avoid this step. Anyhow, i didn't and had to register my chromecast. Created a dummy application as well. And after this my chromecast started showing up on the discovered devices list.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably trying to find the button in Emulator or Preview of the xml file.Which you will never find.

Look in the link given below

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/cast-button#sender-cast-icon-states

You have to understand  that cast button has 4 states, and it becomes visible only when there is a cast device nearby.So if you want to check if the button is there or not.First install the apk on your phone than start your chromecast .After this the button will start appearing on your app.

Note: You have to first register your device on the [google cast sdk developers console](https://cast.google.com/publish/) to be able to test unpublished apps.(which is the case when you are running the sample app.)

Comment: I also faced the same issue. Suppose I want to cast my audio to my TV which has no chromecast and it is smart TV based on Linux OS as a some of Samsung Smart TV. How it will show the cast icon?

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your chromecast after registering it. If you register it, but don't subsequently restart it, you won't see the cast button in the cactool website.

Also, make sure that

1. Your device is registered (before restarting)
2. You are using the Chrome browser
3. Your receiver app is active (try putting your receiver app url in the browser and verify that it loads; check developer tools and make sure that it has pulled in your javascript code)
4. Try using a regular Chromecast device (rather than one built in to a TV)
5. I have read that for some people it makes a difference which google account you are logged in with in the Chrome browser, with at least one account saying that it only worked when logged into a separate account (than the one being used to make the chromecast app)